# Transformation Matrices: $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_j = \sum_{i} H_j^i \mathbf{e}_i$ and $\hat{\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}} = H^{-1}\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensors, change-of-basis

My textbook says the following in an appendix on tensor notation:

> Consider a change of coordinate axes in which the basis vectors $\mathbf{e}_i$ are replaced by a new basis set $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_j$, where $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_j = \sum_{i} H_j^i \mathbf{e}_i$, and $H$ is the basis transformation matrix with entries $H_j^i$. If $\hat{\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}} = (\hat{x}^1, \hat{x}^2, \hat{x}^3)^T$ are the coordinates of the vector with respect to the new basis, then we may verify that $\hat{\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}} = H^{-1}\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}$. Thus, if the basis vectors transform according to $H$ the coordinates of points transform according to the inverse transformation $H^{-1}$.

I don't understand what the last part is saying (and yes, I've made sure to copy it exactly):

> Thus, if the basis vectors transform according to $H$ the coordinates of points transform according to the inverse transformation $H^{-1}$.

I have 2 problems with this part:

1. It seems to me that the syntax is poor, which makes it difficult to try and understand what it is trying to say. Even so, I think I have managed to decipher it (see 2).
2. Beyond the syntax and with regards to mathematics, I'm wondering *why* is it that we use $H$ as the transformation matrix for the basis vectors in $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_j = \sum_{i} H_j^i \mathbf{e}_i$, whereas we use $H^{-1}$ as the transformation matrix for the coordinates of points $\hat{\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}} = H^{-1}\mathbf{\mathrm{x}}$? In other words, I don't understand why we use $H$ for one and $H^{-1}$ for the other? I only have introductory-level linear algebra knowledge, so please explain gently.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to help me understand this.

Comment: Note that if $\hat{e}_i = H^j_i e_j$, then for any vector $x$ we have $x=\hat{x}^i \hat{e}_i =\hat{x}^i H^j_i e_j = x^j e_j$. So $x^j= \hat{x}^i H^j_i$. Which means $\hat{x}^i =[H^{-1}]^i_j x^i$.

Comment: @KelvinLois Thanks for the comment. How did you get $\hat{x}^i =[H^{-1}]^i_j x^i$ from $x^j= \hat{x}^i H^j_i$?

Comment: Consider it as a matrix multiplication. So just take the inverse.

Comment: @KelvinLois please show what matrix multiplication you did to get.

Comment: $[x^i]= H [\hat{x}^i] $ And then multiply both sides by H inverse.

Comment: Sorry i cant type too much. For details you might wanna look at [here](https://www.amazon.com/Course-Modern-Mathematical-Physics-Differential/dp/0521829607) page 81.

Comment: @KelvinLois I see what you’re saying now (see 3.17 on page 84). But I think it should be $\hat{x}^i = [H^{-1}]^j_i x^i$ instead of $\hat{x}^i = [H^{-1}]^i_j x^i$, no?

Comment: When we working with the matrix expression we do not really pay attention to the indices. Thats why i wrote the column vector of $x^i$ and its friend both with indices $i$. But when we working with components expression we should pay attention to the indices. So it should be $\hat{x}^j = [H^{-1}]^j_i x^i$.